# Adding Reference Links

Tags: feature-request

Just wondering how much interest there would be in a new feature to the Stack Exchange platform to have a specific way to add references to answers. As it stands at the present moment the only way to add references for answers is as a list of links at the end of an answer but the way people do this with their answers varies between users and sometimes I have seen formatting done for it which winds up with the references carrying as high of a visual aspect as the answer itself. I am thinking about a Wikimedia style references structure whereby as part of the form for adding answers would be a button for adding references. For each reference added it is appended to the bottom of the answer in smaller text as a link to the reference document if it exists on the net.

Comment: I'm not sure that complicating the UI to make a special field for references would be useful.   I usually do references in the form of [as this article states](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/adding-reference-links):  "the only way to add references for answers is as a list of links at the end of an answer"